# Justifying the procedure of computing $\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{10,000 +\dots}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

Recently I came across this question. Compute $$\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{10,000 +\dots}}}.$$

I know how to do it. By equating the above expression to $x$ (i.e., $x = \sqrt{10+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{10,000 +\dots}}}$) and $x = \sqrt{10+x}$ and so on. But how is this justified? I mean if we take the expression $\sqrt{10+x}$, literally it is equal to $\sqrt{10+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100 +\dots}}}$ which alters the original expression. Can someone clarify my doubt?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand precisely the value you're computing.  Is it: $$\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{1000+\cdots}}}$$

Comment: the third term under the square root is 10,000.

Comment: the 4th term is 100000000

Comment: It might be easier if you'd written $$\sqrt{10+\sqrt{10^2+\sqrt{10^4+\cdots}}}$$ instead.

Comment: @CameronBuie : Not just easier, but also clear. The original question is not clear what is meant to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, it isn't so simple as putting $x=\sqrt{10+x}$--as you've noted, this changes the expression. Now, if you were looking at $\sqrt{10+\sqrt{10+\sqrt{10+\cdots}}}$, that's precisely what you'd do. The reason we can do that, there, is that we're dealing with a sequence defined recursively by $x_1=\sqrt{10}$, $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{10+x_n}$, and then determining the limit of this sequence. That sequence does converge (as it is increasing and bounded above, for example by $10$), so letting $x$ be the limit, we take $n\to\infty$ in the recursion equation $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{10+x_n}$, yielding $x=\sqrt{10+x}$, which we can then use to determine the limit.

---

Let's consider the sequence given by $y_1=\sqrt{10}$, $y_{n+1}=\sqrt{10+y_n\sqrt{10}}$. Then $$y_2=\sqrt{10+10}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100}},$$ $$y_3=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{10}\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100}}}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100+10\sqrt{100}}}=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{100+\sqrt{10,000}}},$$ and so on. Now, **if** this sequence converges (say to $y$), then we take $n\to\infty$ in the equation $y_{n+1}=\sqrt{10+y_n\sqrt{10}}$, yielding $y=\sqrt{10+y\sqrt{10}}$, which we may solve to determine $y$. The trickier part (in this case) is determining an upper bound, so you can prove convergence. From the sounds of it, though, you're supposed to take for granted that it converges, so all you've got to do is the procedure above.

Answer (score 7):

$x=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{10^2+\sqrt{10^4+\cdots}}}$

$\implies \frac x{\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}$ (This is the well-known [Golden Ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio#Alternate_forms))

so, $\frac x{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{ 1+\sqrt 5}{2}$

---

Alternatively, $ \frac x{\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt{1+\frac x{\sqrt{10}}}$

Squaring we get, $\frac {x^2}{10}=1+\frac x{\sqrt{10}}\implies x^2-\sqrt{10}x-10=0$

$\implies x=\frac{\sqrt 10\pm \sqrt {50}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{10}(1\pm\sqrt 5)}{2}$

or $y=\sqrt{1+y}$ putting $\frac x{\sqrt{10}}=y$

$\implies y^2=1+y\implies y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt5}2\implies x=\frac{\sqrt{10}(1\pm\sqrt 5)}{2}$

But $x>0,$ which means $x=\frac{\sqrt{10}(1+\sqrt 5)}{2}$

For the converge, one may check for "Geometric Infinite Surd" [here](http://www.ehow.com/about_5316470_infinite-surds.html).

Comment: I think we cannot take 10 common from the first term i.e., 10

Comment: @RanjanYajurvedi, thanks for your observation, we need to take $\sqrt {10}$ common.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my doubt is, normally the procedure to calculate such expressions is to equate the original expression to x and replacing from second term with to infinity with x. That is x=SQRT(10+x). Doesn't it deviate from the original question?

Comment: You need $\sqrt{2.5}+\sqrt{12.5}$ about 5.1166727, a solution to $\frac x{\sqrt{10}}=\sqrt{1+\frac x{\sqrt{10}}}$

Comment: The third line should have $\frac{x}{\sqrt{10}}$ instead of $\frac{x}{10}$ inside the square root. This yields $x=\frac12\sqrt{10}(\sqrt5+1)$.

Comment: This is helpful, but it shows only that IF IT CONVERGES, then this is its value.

Comment: My doubt is with the procedure not the solution.

Comment: @did, sorry for the mistake, I am rectifying

Comment: How can I cross check the answer?

Comment: @RanjanYajurvedi, I'm not sure about the existence of any procedure to cross check  the value of an infinite surd.

Comment: @RanjanYajurvedi, do you have any further doubt or queries,now? Thanks for the nice question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the OP expressed some doubts about *the procedure not the solution*, here are some elements of reassurance. Let $a=10$, or, more generally, any positive real number.

In any interpretation of the exercise, the value of $x$, if it exists, should correspond to the limit of a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ such that $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}x_n}$, for every $n\geqslant0$. Here is a fact:

> Let $(x_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ denote any sequence defined as above. For every $x_0\geqslant-\sqrt{a}$, $x_n\to\ell_a$, where $\ell_a=\frac12(\sqrt5+1)\sqrt{a}$.

Thus, about any reasonable procedure used to define $x$, first, will succeed, and second, will yield $x=\ell_a$. We happy. (When $a=10$,  $\ell_a=\frac{5+\sqrt5}{\sqrt{2}}$.)

To prove the fact stated above, consider the function $u_a$ defined by $u_a(t)=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}t}$, for every $t\geqslant-\sqrt{a}$. Then $u_a$ is continuous, increasing, such that $t\lt u_a(t)\lt\ell_a$ for every $-\sqrt{a}\leqslant t\lt\ell_a$, $u_a(\ell_a)=\ell_a$, and $\ell_a\lt u_a(t)\lt t$ for every $t\gt\ell_a$.

As a consequence, $x_n=\ell_a$ for every $n\geqslant0$ if $x_0=\ell_a$, $(x_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is increasing and bounded above by $\ell_a$ and converges to $\ell_a$ for every $-\sqrt{a}\leqslant x_0\lt\ell_a$, and $(x_n)_{n\geqslant0}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $\ell_a$ and converges to $\ell_a$ for every $x_0\gt\ell_a$. In every case, $x_n\to\ell_a$.